# Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused) Selenium with C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, runtime-error

I am building an application in C# that uses Selenium Webdriver. I am on Linux and using the latest version of chromedriver. When I try and run the application I get the error: `Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused)` written on the console at least a couple hundred times.

Eventually, I get the following:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.37.544315 (730aa6a5fdba159ac9f4c1e8cbc59bf1b5ce12b7) on port 39969
Only local connections are allowed.
Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused)
Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused)
Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused)
Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused)
Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused)
Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused)
Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused)
```

The application runs as intended after this so it's not a huge deal, but I want to resolve the error - any ideas as to why this error is occuring?

Comment: Please find out where is the chromedriver binary, then give a try `chromedriver  --port=39969` to see you will get same error? If so and same error on other port too, please check your firewall setting on system.

Comment: @yong When I run `chromedriver --port=39969` on the terminal I get the following: `Starting ChromeDriver 2.35.528139 (47ead77cb35ad2a9a83248b292151462a66cd881) on port 39969 
Only local connections are allowed.`

Comment: @yong So I do not get the `Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused)` when I do this

Comment: So chromedriver can launch success, I guess the `connection refuse` comes from each Selenium API invoke, could you turn off the fireware/iptables of your linux, so that any kind of traffic on any port will be allowed. Then run script again.  If the issue still there even turn off fireware,  launch chromedriver manually with cmd: `chromedriver --port=8888 --verbose`, and change the RemoteWebDriver to use this URL `http://localhost:8888`, and run script again, then show us the output in cmd window of chromdriver running.